# Change Event is not working on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to debug and find the error, why Change Event is not working on input field. so i have put breakpoint on change event of jquery while debugging but it skip that .i am not able to find why it is not stopping at breakpoint for debugging.

html part which is generated dynamically only a part is shown here.

```
var p = $('<input type="file" ID="flImage" name="flImage" runat="server" />');
                $("#mainTbl").append(p);
```

script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">      
            $(function () {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var fileName;
                var contentType;
//tried all three trick to envoke change function but not work
                //$('input[name=flImage]').change(function () {
                $("<input type='file' name='flImage' ID='flImage'/>").change(function () {
                //$("input[name=flImage]").on("change", function(){
                    if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
                        $($(this)[0].files).each(function () {
                            var file = $(this);
                            if (regex.test(file[0].name.toLowerCase())) {
                                fileName = file[0].name;
                                contentType = file[0].type;
                                reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
                            } else {
                                alert(file[0].name + " is not a valid image file.");
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
                    }
                });    
</script>
```

After show many advice from comment i'm trying like this to access input element
is it ok `:div.main main-raised > div#pdfFormInsideL1 > table#mainTbl > tbody >tr>'input[name=flImage]`
image given below[image]

Comment: For dynamic elements, delegate event to closest static container: `$("#mainTbl").on('change', 'input[name=flImage]', function(){...});`  https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Your selector `$("<input type='file' name='flImage' ID='flImage'/>")` is totally wrong. I think you wanted `$('#flImage')`

Comment: @A.Wolff   i update on accessing dynamic elements which will form like this is it fine :div.main main-raised > div#pdfFormInsideL1 > table#mainTbl > tbody >tr>'input[name=flImage]

Comment: @A.Wolff Thx it's work "For dynamic elements, delegate event to closest static container".

Answer (score 0):

```js
var p = $('<input type="file" ID="flImage" name="flImage" runat="server" />');
                $("#mainTbl").append(p); 
                
                
$(function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var fileName;
        var contentType;

        $("input[name=flImage]").on("change", function(){
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
                $($(this)[0].files).each(function () {
                    var file = $(this);
                    if (regex.test(file[0].name.toLowerCase())) {
                        fileName = file[0].name;
                        contentType = file[0].type;
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
                    } else {
                        alert(file[0].name + " is not a valid image file.");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
            }
        });    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mainTbl"></div>
```

Comment: @LinkinTED Yes, You can also here after click on `Run code snippet`

Comment: It won't work. When you dynamically add an element, you need event delegation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @LinkinTED Please check your `Jquery` file version

Comment: @LinkinTED  i update on accessing dynamic elements which will form like this is it fine :div.main main-raised > div#pdfFormInsideL1 > table#mainTbl > tbody >tr>'input[name=flImage]